# get infos from screen in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm thinking about creating a bot that would solve some (html) puzzle  games using a pre-defined strategy.

My question : is there any ruby libraries that would allow to "read screen" (*i.e.* check the colors of some pixels on screen) and apply actions (like clicking somewhere, or "press right key" ? )

I know this would be quite easy in python, but I was just wondering wether ruby could do that to save me some time.

Thanks !

Comment: This question is quite broad, and shows no real effort (you may have made some searches, but you give no information). To improve the question, please show what you have done so far - include anything you have searched for and why it is not good for you. Also, questions asking for external resources directly are always off topic - instead please focus on what you are trying to do, what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/browser_testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) and some nice JavaScript driver like [Poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist). You can send [key commands](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#sending-keys), click on [precise coordinates](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#clicking-precise-coordinates) and take [screenshoots](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#taking-screenshots-with-some-extensions). For image manipulation and processing I suggest that you look into [chunky_png](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png).